# PHP Soap Call and Response

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am making a soap call :

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://test.com/collect/test.wsdl');
```

I then use :

```
var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```

This returns the following :

```
2array(43) {
  [0]=>
  string(52) "struct ProcessBrokerLead {
 BrokerRequest request;
}"
  [1]=>
  string(77) "struct ProcessBrokerLeadResponse {
 BrokerResponse ProcessBrokerLeadResult;
}"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "int char"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "duration duration"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "string guid"
  [5]=>
  string(118) "struct BrokerRequest {
 ExternalReference ExternalReference;
 LoanRequest LoanRequest;
 ArrayOfApplicant Applicants;
}"
  [6]=>
  string(249) "struct ExternalReference {
 string IntroducerReference;
 string SubAffiliate;
 string Campaign;
 string ApplicationReference;
 boolean IsSpeculative;
 boolean IsInteractive;
 boolean HasConsentedToCreditSearch;
 boolean HasConsentedForDataSharing;
}"
  [7]=>
  string(211) "struct LoanRequest {
 decimal LoanAmount;
 int LoanTerm;
 InstalmentType PaymentFrequency;
 boolean IsSecured;
 Purpose Purpose;
 ArrayOfSecurity Securities;
 DayOfWeek RepaymentDay;
 decimal InstalmentAmount;
```

How do i Access this data

I have tried

```
$res = $client->ProcessBrokerLead();
print_r($res);
```

I just carry on getting errors, i pretty new to SOAP and i could really use some assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ProcessBrokerLead you took from that output is a data type, not an method call or operation.

To find out which operations you can perform, you would use:

```
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

The output will tell you the response data type, and parameter data types you need to use for each operation.

Then you use `var_dump($client->__getTypes());` to get details about each data type.

It helps to think of `struct` as meaning the same thing as `class`.  So for example, you have this data structure (class) called `ProcessBrokerLead`, and inside that structure is a property called `request`.  `request` is itself another data structure called `BrokerRequest`.